# How to overwrite "left: 80%" from inline CSS

Tags: css, margin, overwrite

I have a third party chatting tool on my site that has preset CSS like this:

```
body. chat {
    left: 80%;
    position: fixed; }
```

I need to overwrite that part with:

```
body. chat{
    right: 0px !important;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0 !important;}
```

This will help to keep the button on the bottom right corner of the browser. And reducing the size of the window won't cut the button in half.

However, I can't overwrite: left: 80%.

I tried with:

```
body. chat{
    left: 0px !important; 
    right: 0px !important;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0 !important;}
```

But left overwrite right in this.

Comment: have you tried auto!important; ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbVbgN

Comment: Did you double check for syntax errors? `0 !important` should basically work (AlexStack's anwer is the right way though), but i see that you are writing `body. chat` so this rule will not apply to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left: initial` to override whatever is set for it. `initial` works with most other CSS attributes too in case you need it.

Comment: I know using !important is not the best practice. But since I don't have control over that tool's css, what other choice do I have ?

Comment: If the answer is right, I could use some points! :) Using !important is ok in this case. You can also load your CSS after the original CSS and use more specific rules. Read about CSS Specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I have to wait another 5 min to accept this answer. Thanks for the info

Comment: No problemo. Feel free to ask any question you have. Cheers.